# Why is "How to introduce yourself in a telephone interview" downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Why is this question [How to introduce yourself in a telephone interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5825/2322) being downvoted so heavily (5 at the time I write this) as well as seemingly on track to be closed?

I understand this question seems really obvious to me (hence my comment) but as best I can tell, the only real problem with the question is that it is slightly on the poll side. Otherwise it is a really good, solid, practical question the asker has.

What am I missing why this question is bad?

---

Edit to add that this was

> closed as off topic by Jim G., SahilMahajanMj, Chad, Yannis Rizos,
>   kolossus yesterday (10/25/2012)

Can you guys explain why you voted to close this? Not to mention `Off Topic` seems like a silly close reason. (It has since been reopened)

Comment: `What am I missing why this question is bad?` It's extremely boring.

Comment: @YannisRizos is "exciting" a criteria for questions on these sites?

Comment: No, of course not. However it might explain _some_ of the downvotes.

Comment: @YannisRizos I think that might be the #1 determining factor for up/downvotes on questions here now that you mention it...

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close, but I don't remember the exact close reason (the displayed close reason is the majority vote). But I probably picked "Off Topic" as to me "How to introduce yourself in a telephone interview" is exactly the same question as "How to introduce yourself on the telephone", which isn't really a problem unique to the workplace.

From [your comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-to-introduce-yourself-in-a-telephone-interview#comment11203_5825):

> "Hello, this is $(MY_NAME)" is how I answer my phone 100% of the time I don't know the number and need to avoid with situations like this – enderland Oct 23 at 16:25

I gather that you also didn't read the question as a workplace problem, why does "Off Topic" seem silly to you?

Comment: btw I'm not claiming my reasoning is correct, just explaining what I thought at the time I voted to close. The question is now open, and that's that.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here which are not necessarily exclusively workplace issues (see most questions related to "how to negotiate", etc).

Comment: @enderland And I think I voted to close most of them ;)